# Searching by a specific variable in a class

Tags: c++, list, iterator, find

I have a list of pointers to classes:

```
list<AbsClient*> clients;
```

AbsClient could be 1 of 3: TempClient , RegisteredClient , VIPClient.

Inside AbsClient there's a protected variable: phone_number.

I need to iterate through the clients list, and search for a specific phone number.

I tried this:

```
    list<AbsClient*>::iterator iter;
    for(iter=clients.begin();iter!=clients.end();++iter)
{
    if(iter->phone_number == phone)
    {

    }
}
```

But it doesn't give me access to the iter->phone_number:

> error: expression must have pointer-to-class type

What's wrong with this line?

P.S is it possible to use the stl::find function and somehow tell it to search by the "phone_number" variable?

Thank you

Comment: `if(iter->phone_number == phone)` should be `if((*iter)->phone_number == phone)` since iter points to value_type of (AbsClient*) another pointer to AbsClient

Comment: @Mr.Anubis if((*iter)->phone_number == phone) gives me an error saying: member AbsClient::phone_number is inaccessable. And: no perator "==" matches these operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of an iterator as a "pointer to an element" of your container. And the type of an element in your container is a `AbsClient*`—another pointer. So, at least syntactically, you're in a double-pointer situation, so you need to change how you dereference your iterator:

```
(*iter)->phone_number == phone
```

Your post says that `phone_number` is a protected member, though, and you can't access protected variables when you're not inside that class or a derived class, so you either need to use an accessor method or change the visibility of your data member.

And no, you can't use `std::find` to do this (at least not directly), but you *can* use `std::find_if`:

```
iter = std::find_if(clients.begin(), clients.end(),
    [phone](AbsClient* cl) { return cl->phone_number == phone; });
```

If you aren't using C++11, then it's a bit more verbose:

```
struct MatchPhone {
    explicit MatchPhone(PhoneNumber p) : phone(p) {}
    bool operator()(AbsClient* cl) {
        return cl->phone_number == phone;
    }
    PhoneNumber phone;
};

// ...
iter = std::find_if(clients.begin(), clients.end(), MatchPhone(phone));
// ...
```

Comment: what is 'PhoneNumber' in your struct? did you mean my variable phone_number? or some type...? edit: it's a type i guess. so i need string.

Comment: @AdamDe The type of your `phone_number` variable wasn't in your question, so I made one up.

Comment: i changed phone_number to be public, and now i have this error: no operator "==" matches these operands (on line: cl->phone_number == phone). edit: and both of them, phone and phone_number, are strings.

Comment: @AdamDe Using my psychic powers, I have deduced that you have declared `phone_number` to be a different type than `phone`. Or they're some strange string type with no `operator==` declared.

Comment: @AdamDe Then they're not `std::string`s. Did you write your own string type?

Comment: Oh you're right... i should've #included <string>. Now it seems to be working. I'll update here what happens next. Thank you